# Xcode project renamed and now it is lost

Tags: ios, xcode

I was trying to rename my Xcode project and I followed the apple developer guide and went to View -> Utilities -> Open file inspector and changed the name. Now the initial project only has the pods and the new project created won't run. Is there a way to restore it? I have been working on this project for months and would be devastated if it was lost.

Comment: Just as a side note, it would be good to look at using git or some other version control.  That way you could never lose your project.  www.github.com

Answer (score 4):

> would be devastated if it was lost

That's what version control is for (git).

But if you don't have a git commit to revert to, don't worry; there is a simple solution. Start a new empty project based on one of the built-in app templates and just migrate everything from your old project into that. No actual files have been deleted by whatever you did, so there should be no difficulty about this.